# Dynamic content scrollbar error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have a problem with adding dynamic content to a webpage.

The javascript loads some html and swap the divholder's innerhtml. Basically is a

```
$("#mydiv").load("some.html");
```

My problem is that when you get a huge page, it created a huge scrollbar, then, after swaping the html for a smaller html, the scrollbars aren't being resized.

eg: http://jode.com.br/joe/scrollbarerror.png

Using firebug, you can see that the highlighted content is the window but the scrollheight is just a lot bigger than the contents of it

It is happening on firefox and ie, but not in chrome. Using chrome, hte scrollbars are updated to only scroll content

any help?

Comment: `height:100%` on the body tag is evil...

Comment: my code is just a load with jQuery into some div and this div will have very different heights becuase of the html

Comment: I don't get it. If body has 100% height, what use is overflow: hidden? Or does it even overflow at all? Seems that 100% height, the page will just keep expanding with more content to me. Should try remove overflow:hidden to see if new content will auto resize?

Comment: the HTML has a overflo-y:scroll. I didn't do this in the begining... It was a body with overflow-y: scroll, but because of this bug I kept trying other stuff to fix it. So neither puting overflow-y: scroll on window or on the body did it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution right now is create a div that holds all the content. The div's scrollbar is being updated to the right size when the content changes.

THen I used the method:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#MainContentHolder {
  height: 100%;
}
```

with this, the maincontentholder got the right scrollbars and is being updated correctly.

many thanks who tried to help!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I guess the bug is because of your `height:100%` on the body tag.

Why do you need it ? You shouldn't do that :) Try removing it and tell us if the bug's still here.

Comment: still the same without the height: 100%